What is the distribution of voting fraud over user rep and account age?
Since voting fraud is a big focus of the discussion of the 1-rep voting experiment, I'm curious to get some more informed estimates of how much more voting fraud would occur if users could vote at 1-rep (i.e., something better than my stupid estimate that assumed that fraud is uniformly distributed over all users).
There are two variables of interest to me: account reputation, and account age.
A 3D graph (with its bucketed data file) would be awesome, but two 2D graphs (one kernel density function for fraud distribution over account reputation, and another over account age) would also be ok.
The one over account age could be used as-is pretty easily, but the one over account rep would require extrapolating for the range [0-15) (and yes, I know that reality would be more complicated to take such an extrapolation seriously, due to the effort it takes to earn rep (however small I simultaneously claim it to be)).
Ideally I'd like to see the variable values (reputation and account age) at the time that the user committed voting fraud (maybe just the most recent one, if multiple offences would mess up the properness of the analysis), but if that's not feasible (I assume nobody takes note of the user's reputation and account age at the time they commit voting fraud (... actually, I assume suspension history would include suspension date and reason, and then you could just recalculate score by replaying votes received up to that point)), then take the variables as their current value, for any account that ever committed voting fraud.

It would be interesting to know what if any records of historic voting fraud the company has (in general terms, so as to avoid giving away details on fraud detection methods). Since unless they are able to assess a baseline of fraud, how can they even begin to assess in an objective manner an increase in fraud. (any subjective assessment is going to be assumed to be rigged)

@user1937198 The tests are going to run over only a few weeks, so even if they don't have a historical baseline it's simple enough (and possibly even preferable) to collect that data now or after the test.

Right now I don't really know what I would be interested in. I find the recent XZ utils backdoor exploit to be kind of mindblowing. Before that exploit I would say that activity should also be an important factor. A person asking only questions has more dodgy potential than someone who also answers, edits, votes, reviews and participates on meta. Except now we're learning that this can also be social engineering at play. Make yourself look like a good guy, play the long game and strike when nobody is paying attention.

@Gimby Confidence games go back thousands of years--the concept is nothing new. Only the systems within which scammers operate change.

The data would need to be aggregated to avoid running afoul of the moderator team's policy not to comment on suspensions or reveal non-public information about specific accounts.

@Gimby And add to that, there are fairly easy to find sites that offer SO accounts for sale.  I have no idea how good SO is at catching these sort of account transfers, but no one has any real way of knowing if any account is in control of the same person day to day.

Regardless of the experiment that they intend to conduct soon, I have always wondered about the prevalence of voting fraud on SO. The year in moderation posts provide a very blurry picture of this through the number of suspensions, warnings, and escalations to CM (all of which could be for a number of reasons). It's about time they showed the numbers.

@TylerH sure. could aggregate into buckets to avoid giving specific rep numbers and dates. that could also mean not having to make KDFs (I'd still like the buckets to be pretty granular though)

As stated elsewhere, while I expect fraud to be a problem, I see the big problem coming from folks upvoting harmful posts simply because they lack the experience to see the easy answer as a danger. And when Stack Overflow is no more trustworthy than Geeks For Geeks, it's game over, man! Game over!

@Gimby and the misfortune is that countering this kind of social engineering is only doable by requiring real identity proof. I can't imagine SO asking for a piece of identity in order to vote.

bring back the [tag:not-a-robot-badge], I say! (joking) @Cœur. or make people pay $8? (also joking)

@starball Glad that you are joking. Not only has Not A Robot been fooled by a cunning robot, but it is subject to manipulation by Skrulls.
